# How can I disable and enable an ArcGIS 10 Add-In button?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, development, .net

Is there a way to enable / disable Add-In buttons / tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation this can be done in the OnUpdate method, [Add-in coding patterns](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/0001/0001000000zz000000.htm#Enabling)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Just curious, if the OnUpdate method is likely checked often, how much impact does a code placed there have on performance?  Suppose I am checking the state of the editor and enable/disable commands based on it. Where is the best place to declare the editor? If Editor is used throughout the Add-In, should I declare it once globally say in a module?

Comment: @Jakub, the documentation states "Particularly time consuming operations, such as database queries, should never be performed within OnUpdate." So if you do checks of properties of objects in memory I don't think you will get in any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I got that wrong the first time .  Not sure why I was thinking checked when you said enabled.

But enabled is boolean just like checked:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Enabled_Property/001v000000s0000000/

http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#585OjyuBOxM/trunk/Umbriel.ArcMap.Addin/ShowSelectByLocation/ShowSelectByLocationButton.cs&q=Enabled%20package:http://umbriel%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=70

<strike>Checked property.</strike>

For example, check out line #51 :[http://code.google.com/p/umbriel/source/browse/trunk/Umbriel.ArcMap.Addin/Umbriel.ArcMap.Addin.EditorTrack/EditorTrackToggleButton.cs#51][1]

[1]: http://code.google.com/p/umbriel/source/browse/trunk/Umbriel.ArcMap.Addin/Umbriel.ArcMap.Addin.EditorTrack/EditorTrackToggleButton.cs#51